# Azure: Should a CloudStorageAccount be made static on a web server?

Tags: azure, httpclient, azure-table-storage

I have dozens of Azure Storage accounts and depending on the current HTTP session, I execute CRUD operations against a specific storage account. I have a single instance of `HttpClient` for other API calls (i.e. calls that are not related to Azure Storage). See [this](https://medium.com/@nuno.caneco/c-httpclient-should-not-be-disposed-or-should-it-45d2a8f568bc) for the reasons behind.

For Azure Storage, I'm using the .NET SDK leveraging classes like `CloudStorageAccount` and `CloudTable`. Is there a similar re-use for Azure Storage so that the web server does not open connections over and over? For example, should a `CloudStorageAccount` instance be made static and re-used across the application? I can't find any documentation on official Microsoft recommendation.

Considering I have many storage accounts, I'd have to cache a connection to every single one separately. I'm not sure if doing this is a good practice or not.

Comment: Look here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/antipatterns/improper-instantiation/. This shows why creating one connection and then not closing it is a clever idea.

Comment: @HassanRaza There is no mention of `CloudStorageAccount` in that article though. I'm specifically looking for connections to Azure Storage.

Comment: any connection same concept applies